# Is there a timepicker widget available for Wear OS application?

Tags: android, wear-os, timepicker, android-timepicker

I am working on a project in which the user is supposed to enter a start- and endtime. I figured this could be done beautifully with a timepicker, like the one used in the native alarm app. The problem is that I can't seem to find any record of this being available to the public. I have tried to use the standard timepicker for Android phones but this just doesn't fit with a Wear OS layout.

My question: Is there a way to get the timepicker from the alarm app into your own project?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?